# how to create I tag using Chtml in _form in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

how to create I tag using Chtml in _form in yii
I try using below sentence but till not working

```
<?php echo CHtml::i('Text', array('id'=>'idTextField','width'=>100,'maxlength'=>100); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try please

```
echo CHtml::tag('i', array('id'=>'idTextField','width'=>100,'maxlength'=>100), 'Text');
```

PS: I'm not sure what are you trying to achive by giving it `width` and `maxlength` but they are not the valid attributes for `<i />` tag

I'll suggest you to rather use `<em>` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp